# Convert string date to object date for database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

How do I convert date "20170101" to Date object so that Doctrine Date Time accept it for the database?

I have tried this;

```
$date = "20170101";
$date = strtotime($date);
$newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date);

$order->setDate($newDate);
```

But I still get an error;

> DateTimeType ->convertToDatabaseValue ('2017-01-01 00:00:00',
> object(PostgreSQL92Platform))
>
> Call to a member function format() on string

Current dates that are already in the database are the same format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', '20170101');
```